# How to transform JSON object using Amazon States Language?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

##### Problem

I need to transform the state machine input for a Task using the keys from one object (which we'll call `obj1`) in the input and a separate key-value pair in the input (which we'll call `obj2`). Several keys in `obj1` are optional parameters so I can't assume the keys that will be present *a priori*. Additionally, several other key-value pairs may exist that are irrelevant to the Task and so shall not be included in the `payload`.

I'm specifically looking for a single Step Functions Task definition that solves this problem.

##### Example

State machine Task input:

```json
{
    "obj1": { "a": 1, "b": "foo" },
    "obj2": { "c": 2, "d": "bar" },
    "obj3": "baz",
    "obj4": { ... }
}
```

Transformed input for Step Functions Task:

```json
{
    "payload": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": "foo",
        "obj2": { "c": 2, "d": "bar" }
    }
}
```

##### Attempts

I've been attempting to solve this problem using AWS Step Functions [Intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) to no avail. `States.JsonMerge` won't work since I need the key "obj2" to be present in the `payload` object, and I don't want irrelevant key-value pairs such as "obj1", "obj3", or "obj4" to be in the `payload`. `States.Format` seemed promising using the below syntax, but it doesn't appear Amazon States Language (ASL) observes the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Not sure if it's a syntax issue or if it's simply not possible using ASL.

```yaml
MyTask:
    Type: Task
    Resource: arn:aws-us-gov:states:::states:startExecution.sync:2
    Parameters:
      StateMachineArn: "${my_sfn_arn}"
      Input:
        payload.$: "States.Format({ ...$.obj1, 'obj2.$': $.obj2 })"
```

That Task definition failed to deploy with the following error message:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid State Machine Definition: 'SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: The value for the field 'payload.$' must be a valid JSONPath or a valid intrinsic function call...
```

> Note: I know this can be accomplished using a Lambda function, but this same problem exists in several Step Functions workflows so my question is only interested in an ASL-native solution for transforming the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `JsonMerge` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate)  to "spread" `obj1`'s keys.

### Solution 1:  Exactly match the expected output

Add a Pass state before `MyTask` to isolate `obj2`.

```json
    "Obj2": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": { "obj2.$": "$.obj2" },
      "Next": "MyTask"
    },
```

Then merge that output with `obj1`'s keys.  We reference `obj1` from the execution's `$$` [Context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) object:

```yaml
Input: 
    payload.$: "States.JsonMerge($, $$.Execution.Input.obj1, false)"
```

### Solution 2: Simpler if the `obj1` key can stay

```yaml
Input: 
    payload.$: "States.JsonMerge($.obj1, $, false)"
```

Given your input, the task receives the 3 desired keys in the right shape, but keeps a redundant `obj1` key:

```json
"payload": {
    "a": 1, ✅
    "b": "foo", ✅
    "obj1": {"a": 1, "b": "foo"},
    "obj2": {"c": 2, "d": "bar"} ✅
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, @fedonev. I did pursue the approach you share, and should have addressed that in my problem statement. Having the redundant `obj1` data is an undesirable artifact in the `payload` because in my real problem there are several other keys that are in the state machine input (i.e. `$`) that are not needed in the payload. These redundant keys can be confusing to see downstream since they are not relevant to the downstream Task. I'll update my post to be more clear about the requirement.

Comment: @T.Pubz.  Glad to help.  I added a variant that doesn't retain the `obj1` key.